# SQLServer2012Dialect will work for SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

does the dialect SQLServer2012Dialect work with SQL Server 2014?

Comment: you mean t-sql syntax? yes ;)

Comment: oh yes, check the Backward Compatibility notes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143532(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: and how about SQLServer2008Dialect will that work with SQL Server 2014?

Comment: check the notes, it's all there, what's not supported

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, T-SQL that works on SQL Server 2012 will work in SQL Server 2014 as well.  The exceptions are documented in the SQL Server Books Online topic [SQL Server Database Engine Backward Compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms143532(v=sql.120).aspx).  Discontinued, breaking, and behavior changes are documented.  Note that use of undocumented features or behavior in SQL 2012 may change without notice and break your code when running under SQL 2014.

One should also avoid using announced deprecated features in new development and plan to remediate existing code as the opportunity arises.